# Teradata storing extra spaces beyond the column's character limit

Tags: java, spring-boot, teradata

I'm having an issue with data in Teradata where extra spaces are added beyond the specifies column limit. This is true for all the character type columns everywhere. Please look at the below screenshots.

We are having to trim the contents in our Java logic layer or sometimes in the sql query itself which is not convenient. I couldn't find much in the documentations as well. Has anyone else faced this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not stored like this in Teradata. Quick guess: Might be based on the session character set, 10 digits + plus 10 spaces, Java expects 10 UTF-16, but gets 10 UTF-8 characters and fills with spcaes?

Comment: The screenshots are from Teradata studio ide and this is pretty much read only data. So there's no involvement of java at this point.

Comment: Well, Studio is Java based. Try switching the session charset to UTF16....